# android photoshop actions obstacles

Tags: android, photoshop, effects

I'm in order to make an android app that can add actions on the images, but there are some obstacles.
In fact I know how to make actions in photoshop but I don't know how can I make it in android programming . so Is there any idea or tutorial of how can I make it ?

Comment: Please revise your question, and perhaps add some code samples. It's not clear what you are trying to do. What does Photoshop have to do with android development?

Comment: NO. You simply can't use atn files nor psd files in Android. The only thing you can do is to reproduce what PhotoShop does in basic steps: lighten, darken, desaturate, apply a color filter...